# iOS app goes crash on startup after updating from the app store

Tags: iphone, ipad

iOS App goes crash on startup. After updating from the app store.

Few customer complained that my live iOS app goes crash while they update from old to new.
I don't have any logs right even not older build.

But the app is working fine if they remove and reinstall the fresh app from store.

What should I do here.. :(

Comment: Is it using any kind of CoreData and did you recently update the Schema?

Comment: You should try to emulate the process as closely as possible. Connect your device to XCode, install the old version of your app, now run your new app in debug mode (making sure that the new debug version overwrites the existing app). This always works for me.

Comment: Test the upgrade yourself while debugging in Xcode, with a breakpoint set for all exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion for future releases is to include Crashlytics/Crittercism etc. to get instant crash reports. The last thing you would want is to wait for 36 - 72 hrs to get iTunes crash logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the crash logs in iTunes connect. Most likely there is some incompatibility between old data stored in the app and this version. Other than asking your customers to delete and then reinstall, you will have to issue an update that resolves the crash.

The crash logs in iTunes Connect will give you the call stack where it crashes. You don't need your own logs except for more info.

Comment: App is behaving absolutely fine, if we remove the older build and reinstall the new one.  Actually the problem is I don't have the older build to install the new one on top of it.

Comment: @DeepakKhare Use the archive you created to send to Apple. In Xcode Organizer, go to that archive and choose to distribute an AdHoc version.

Comment: @DeepakKhare did you look at your crash logs? I understand that your app is fine with a fresh install. The things I suggested are common problems for when there is an issue updating from an older version.

Comment: there are many issues are raised with my app.. few of the customer reported after the update client goes crash each time while the remove and fresh install. don't know whats going wrong with my app..

Comment: some times crash log says - 

libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary

I don't know with this log..

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is you make a method on app start up so if the data isn't the same as the one in the current version and tell it to delete the data.