# After update my app from app store, my app cannot open

Tags: ios, swift, version

I try trigger new version available at app store, then i will redirect user to app store. Then inside there i update the app. After finish download, i click open inside app store then my app will open a splash screen then it will auto close. I not get any crash log. This is my code.

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
        do {
            let update = try self.needsUpdate()

            print("update",update)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if update{
                    self.popupUpdateDialogue();
                }

            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }


func popupUpdateDialogue(){
    var versionInfo = ""
    do {
        versionInfo = try self.getAppStoreVersion()
    }catch {
        print(error)
    }


    let alertMessage = "Please update this app to version "+versionInfo;
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Version Available", message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    let okBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Update", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        if let url = URL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/sg/app/myApp/idxxxx"),
            UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
        }
    })
    let noBtn = UIAlertAction(title:"Skip this Version" , style: .destructive, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    })
    alert.addAction(okBtn)
    alert.addAction(noBtn)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


func needsUpdate() -> Bool {
    let infoDictionary = Bundle.main.infoDictionary
    let appID = infoDictionary!["CFBundleIdentifier"] as! String
    let url = URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/sg/lookup?bundleId=\(appID)")
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
    let lookup = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! , options: [])) as? [String: Any]
    if let resultCount = lookup!["resultCount"] as? Int, resultCount == 1 {
        if let results = lookup!["results"] as? [[String:Any]] {
            if let appStoreVersion = results[0]["version"] as? String{
                let currentVersion = infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
                if !(appStoreVersion == currentVersion) {
                    print("Need to update [\(appStoreVersion) != \(currentVersion)]")
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

I really dont know why the app will auto terminate/close. I also already checked on this link [App Crash when after updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47988360/app-crash-when-after-updating), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795920/ios-app-goes-crash-on-startup-after-updating-from-the-app-store,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409323/ios-app-cannot-be-opened-after-update but still not get what solution for this issue.

Comment: Running same version of application from xcode doesn't produce this crash? Does your xcode show any of those crash reports? For starters I would implement one of the crash reporting frameworks so you are up to date with crashes in the future. When you have crash log everything is easier.

Comment: Application from xcode is 1.6 .. and from app store 1.7 .. both can run smoothly. I directly run app version 1.6 from xcode, working without crash. From app store also same, when directly download and install, working fine. I archive the app version 1.6 from xcode and distribute for testing, it working.  But inside the app, i prompt new version from app store and update app from there , then tried open my app then it will open around 2-3 second then auto close..

Comment: Crashlytic report never sent report about that. look like it not crash.

Comment: Huh strange. But Crashlytics should report it in case the error happens. Are you sure you configured it right? Try performing manual crash just to make sure it is working.

Comment: ya totally sure Crashlytics already right because i got report for other crash .